# Document font color is changing after doing insertFileFromBase64

Tags: office-js

I tried inserting file in word with word api insertFileFromBase64,file is inserted sucessfully but color,font are changing after inserting document into word,header is not inserted too.Please suggest how i will retain original document.

original document image
[image]

inserted document image
[image]

What i am doing is file is present inside  our server i am getting the file by hitting api then converting into base64 then i am inserting the file into word through word api,which is inserting differently but while downloading same file from server is same as original.i have uploaded file to server through office api too.

Answer (score 0):

2 things you need to consider here

1. By design we do not overwrite header/footers with the insertFile method, to prevent overrides of existing ones.
2. Are you using an existing style name for that text? (cause we also don't override existing styles)

thanks

Comment: thanks,yes we have existing style of original document is century gothic and font is 22 after inserting it is changing to callibri and font is 11.

Comment: So how can I override styles if it's needed? What was the design behind not replacing if you specify "replace"?